# How to create an option in a select dropdown that has no value in PHP

Tags: php, forms

Below is code I use to determine the options of a `select` dropdown.

The problem I'm having is that, when neither November or May has been set, I expect the value of the first option to read `value=""`. However, PHP ignores the quotes and does not include them in the HTML resulting in just `value`. The reason why I need the quotes, is because I am using the form attribute `required` to validate the form, and when the `value` is not `""`, validation considers the select as filled in.

I have tried `value=\"\"`,   `value=\"''\"` and  `value=\"""\"` among many other variations, but nothing seems to be working.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
function month() {
    global $link; 

    if(isset($_GET['month'])){
        $month=$_GET{'month'};
        if($month=='May') {
            echo "  
                <option value=\"May\" selected=\"selected\">May</option>
                <option value=\"November\">November</option>
                ";
        } else if($month=='November'){
            echo "  
                <option value=\"May\">May</option>
                <option value=\"November\" selected=\"selected\">November</option>
                ";
        } 
    } else {
        echo "
            <option value=\"\" disabled selected hidden>Month</option>
            <option value=\"May\">May</option>
            <option value=\"November\">November</option>
            ";
    }
}
```

Comment: `value=\"\"` would be escaped to `value=""` when it's printed in doublequotes, so that should do what you want. https://eval.in/693972 - what's the output when you tried that?

Comment: "However, PHP ignores the quotes and does not include them in the HTML resulting in just value". Are you sure you're not mistaking the output of your browser console for the output of php? php will output quotes using this code.

Comment: why do you need \" ???

Comment: you can use single quotes for values as well. Why disabled? It must be enable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using single quote (' ') for String in echo and double quote (" ") for value attribute in select tag:

```
echo '<option value="May" selected="selected">May</option>
      <option value="November">November</option>
';
```

That may help.